# strtof() function misplacing decimal place

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, strtod

I have a string `"1613894376.500012077"` and I want to use `strtof` in order to convert to floating point `1613894376.500012077`.  The problem is when I use `strtof` I get the following result with the decimal misplaced `1.61389e+09`.  Please help me determine how to use `strof` properly.

Comment: The conversion was successful.  It's a matter of how you're displaying it.

Comment: Floats only have approximately 6 or 7 decimal digits of accuracy, so 1.61389 x 10^9 seems about right.

Answer (score 4):

A typical  [`float`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) is 32-bit and can only represent exactly about 2<sup>32</sup> different values.  "1613894376.500012077" is not one of those.

"1.61389e+09" is the same value as "1613890000.0" and represents a close  value that `float` can represent.

The 2 closest `float`s are:

```
1613894272.0 
1613894400.0 // slightly closer to 1613894376.500012077
```

Print with more precision to see more digits.

Comment: Thank you, I switched to  `strtod()` and in order to properly print with more precision used `std::fixed` and `std::setprecision(9)`.

Answer (score 1):

The decimal point is not misplaced. The notation “1.61389e+09” means 1.61389•10<sup>9</sup>, which is 1,613,890,000., which has the decimal point in the correct place.

The actual result of `strtof` in your computer is probably 1,613,894,400. This is the closest value to 1613894376.500012077 that the IEEE-754 binary32 (“single”) format can represent, and that is the format commonly used for `float`. When you print it with `%g`, the default is to use just six significant digits. To see it with more precision, print it with `%.999g`.

Answer (score 0):

The number `1613894376.500012077` is equivalent (the same number up to the precision of the machine as `1.61389e+09`.)  The `e+09` suffix means that the decimal point is located nine decimal digits right the place it has been placed (or that the number is multiplied by `10` to the ninth power).  This is a common notation in computer science called scientific notation.